# How to get all TextBox controls of a Form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I am trying to access the `TextBox` controls of a `Form` which are in a `Panel` inside a `GroupBox` as well as any other `TextBox` controls on the form but I am unable to access them. This is what I have tried:

```
For Each ctl As Control In Me.Controls
    If ctl.GetType Is GetType(GroupBox) Then
    'now that we have the groupboxes and panels on this form 
    'loop through them and get their textboxes
        Dim ctrl = CType(ctl, Control)
        For Each ctrl In ctl.Controls
            ....
```

Comment: Use the find method of the control collection it will search parent and child containers. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @MarkHall The OP needs to find all `TextBox` controls and `Find` method is only helpful when you need to find an exact control that you know its name.

Comment: @Reza it returns control collection of all matches, it depends on his naming convention, you do not have to give it the complete name.

Comment: @MarkHall have you tested that? for example if you have `TextBox1` and `TextBox2` and use `Me.Controls.Find("Text", True)` you expect both controls in the result while no controls will be found this way.

Comment: @Reza  Yes. It has bit me in the past where I searched for TextBox1 and got it and TextBox10,11,12..... Back also

Comment: @MarkHall Are you sure that was in [tag:winforms]? Maybe you had made a custom extension method or something else? Testing this is really easy and it works only for exact match.

Comment: I use the 'txt' prefix when naming my textboxes I follow the naming conventions as close as possible. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yo can create a method to find all descendants of a control this way:

```
Private Function GetAllControls(control As Control) As IEnumerable(Of Control)
    Dim controls = control.Controls.Cast(Of Control)()
    Return controls.SelectMany(Function(ctrl) GetAllControls(ctrl)).Concat(controls)
End Function
```

Then you can use it to find all `TextBox` descendants of your form:

```
Dim textboxes = Me.GetAllControls(Me).OfType(Of TextBox)().ToList()
For Each item As TextBox In textboxes
    MessageBox.Show(item.Name)
Next
```

Comment: Just a quick follow up question , I'm wondering how to only select enabled controls on the form , I know in the for each item I can check if its empty or if the control is enabled but how would I alter the GetAllControls function to only get the enabled ones as I don't fully understand this IEnumerable concept (I'll research this tonight after hours.. )

Comment: In the for loop, check `If (item.Enabled)`

Comment: Sorry , see my comment above again I was editing it as I commented without it being completed on accident. I want to alter the function GetAllControls to only select what I need seems more efficient than checking in each for loop for different controls I 'got'

Comment: After `GetAllControls`, you can simply use a linq `Where`

Comment: OK thanks , looks like I have homework tonight :) Need to learn IEnumerable and its functionality

Comment: `Dim textboxes = Me.GetAllControls(Me).OfType(Of TextBox)().Where(Function(x) x.Enabled = True)`

Comment: The above code postpones your homework but it doesn't cancel the homework for always ;)