# How Do I Change ForeColor of all Labels in a Form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am writing down a simple schedule planner app using WinForms in Visual Basic .NET, and I have this "Edit Preferences" where I would want the user to be able to change colors of all labels. I tried to use this code:

```
Public Sub darkMode(ByVal darkModeOn As Boolean)
    If darkModeOn Then
        For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
            If c IsNot lblTitle Then
                If TypeOf c Is Label Then DirectCast(c, Label).ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)
            ElseIf TypeOf c Is Panel Then
                For Each pnlPanel As Panel In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)()
                    pnlPanel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(66, 66, 66)
                Next
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

But when I run that code, it only changes the `ForeColor` of the `Label`s that are immediate children of the form and the changes does not apply to `Label`s that are inside other containers like `Panel`s. Is there any way to change the `ForeColor` of all `Label`s, even those that are not immediate children of the `Form`?

Comment: [How to get textbox from panel inside groupbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33847693/how-to-get-textbox-from-panel-inside-groupbox)

Comment: Thanks! :D That's great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the changing the If ElseIf helps you out.

```
For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is Panel Then
            For Each pnlPanel As Panel In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)()
                pnlPanel.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(66, 66, 66)
            Next
        ElseIf c IsNot lblTitle Then
            If TypeOf c Is Label Then DirectCast(c, Label).ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)
        End If
    Next
```