# Is there a way to iterate through all the controls in my project?

Tags: vb.net, loops, types

I would like to know if there is a way to iterate through all the controls in my project. Be them on a WinForm, or on an UserControl, even if they're not loaded. I would like to do this so I can get the `.Tag` property for every control, along with its name and parent.

What I have so far is that I can get every type in My namespace, but from there I don't know what to do.

```
Private Function GetTypesInNamespace(ByVal assembly As Assembly, ByVal [nameSpace] As String) As Type()
    Return assembly.GetTypes().Where(Function(t) String.Equals(t.[Namespace], [nameSpace], StringComparison.Ordinal)).ToArray()
End Function
```

Comment: I know that asking WHY is usually bad responce, but - why you need such information?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66298355/14171304

Comment: The link from dr.null was almost what i needed.. The thing is, i want to iterate through all controls i have in all containers in my project (forms or usercontrols) so i can build a treeview with them. I need that so i can, then add a tag to only those which i select from the treeview.

Comment: "All the controls you have in your project" is not clear actually. Your function gets Types, but those are not instantiated, so you don't get actual instances of objects, so you don't get Tags, etc. This is further confirmed since you start with an Assembly which just lists types. If you want instances, then this is not to be done on an Assembly, rather a running application. So while it's an interesting idea, I think you need to clarify what you are actually hoping to do, and again, why.

Comment: To make it more clear: i have a mysql table where i want to store some info about the controls (buttons, textboxes, dgv_cells, listboxes, and so on). The problem i get with the code form the post you pointed me to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66297865/how-to-solve-unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-windows-forms-form-in-vb-net/66298355#66298355) is that i get a 'System.MissingMethodException' and i can't use it on usercontrols (which in turn have their own controls).

Comment: i wasn't expecting this to be so difficult... i understand not everything is loaded at runtime, but i was hoping there would be an easy way to iterate to each class and get it's components and their properties... i mean, after all, they are stored in my project and i can easly see / modify their details...

Comment: As to the why, i was hoping that, after i could save those infos, i could use fetch them and update my app with them. For instance, i allow the user to change position of a control (lets say button) at runtime, but then, when the form is reloaded, i want to retrieve the default positon and put it there.

Comment: If you _change position of a control (lets say button) at runtime_, and desire to place it in the same position when the application is loaded next time, store the information in a configuration file. When the application is started the next time, read the configuration file and place the controls accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to ignore Namespace for this. You can add it if you like. But this function does what your function purported to do.

```vb
Public Function getAllTypesOfControl(assembly As Assembly) As IEnumerable(Of Type)
    Return assembly.GetTypes().
        Where(Function(t) t.IsSubclassOf(GetType(ContainerControl))).
        SelectMany(Function(container) container.GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Public)).
        Where(Function(f) f.FieldType.IsSubclassOf(GetType(Control))).
        Select(Function(f) f.FieldType)
End Function
```

Now, you are left with all the Types of all the Controls which are defined in Controls which are ContainerControls. This should include controls defined inside Forms and UserControls, as you mentioned.

Can you do something with this? I don't think so, since you are hoping to access *instances* of controls. To do this, you shouldn't be dealing in the regime of Assembly, rather your *runtime*, which should have your instantiated controls. I think?

You may want to look at [Application.OpenForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0#System_Windows_Forms_Application_OpenForms), and iterate all open forms, and return all controls.

```vb
Public Function getAllInstantiatedControls() As IEnumerable(Of Control)
    Return Application.OpenForms.Cast(Of Form).
        SelectMany(Function(openForm) openForm.Controls.Cast(Of Control)().
            Select(Function(c) c.Controls.Cast(Of Control).Append(c))).
        SelectMany(Function(c) c)
End Function
```

You probably want the second one, because you can't just purely act on Types, as I understand you want to store controls properties. So let me break down your problem. [You said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70213545/is-there-a-way-in-vb-net-to-iterate-trough-all-the-controls-in-myproject/70218582#comment124127766_70213545)

> ...[components in forms] are stored in my project and i can easly see / modify their details...

yes, but do you know how those details are stored? In fact, they are not stored, but set when the form is constructed. Actually, Visual Studio needs to run `InitializeComponent` in order to show you the designer - every time you make a change to a control. So the details are in fact stored like this (in the designer code, Form1.Designer.vb) with a Button named Button1 on it.

Design

[image]

Form1.Designer.vb

```vb
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        ' ...
        Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        '
        'Button1
        '
        Me.Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(157, 103)
        Me.Button1.Name = "Button1"
        Me.Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
        Me.Button1.TabIndex = 3
        Me.Button1.Text = "Button1"
        Me.Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'Form1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(203, 114)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
        Me.Name = "Form1"
        Me.Text = "Form1"
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)
    End Sub

    Friend WithEvents Button1 As Button
End Class
```

You can modify or delete that button and watch the code change or disappear from Form1.Designer.vb. So your "details" are stored in code. This is what the "Visual" in Visual Basic means behind the scenes.

So these details are only set when you run InitializeComponent, which means they are set two ways:

1. In Visual Studio Form1 Design view
2. When an application is run and a Form1 instance is created

Other than these two ways, the control properties do NOT have your values, and would only have default values (but this is really an impossible situation and of dubious relevance).

Knowing this, you must access the instances of controls, which is achieved with the Application.OpenForms option. I think you can load all controls, and write to some settings file or database, and also read back and find controls and update them based on the settings file or database. I'm not writing that though. I think I answered your question.

Comment: Thanks a great bunch! I don't have anymore time tonight to test it thoroughly but the first function looks like what i needed. Also it looks from another planet for me, honestly. I mean, i understand what it does, but i'm stumped of its simplicity and also complexity. Is there a thorough documentation for these type of queries?

Comment: Also, i'm not trying to access any instance. This will be only for saving bulk info about already designed controls in the IDE/Designer. When i'll need any property of any control, i intend to use it on a running form / control as me.controls([DataTable.Field(NameOfControl)).property = [DataTable](FieldValue) --> not a code, obviously :) Thanks again and can't wait to test it tomorrow

Comment: @AdelinaAndreeatrandafir there is some contradiction in your last comment, looking at `i'm not trying to access any instance` and `i intend to use it on a running form`. See, controls don't have property values until the controls are instantiated. I will post some designer code to illustrate this.

Comment: Apparently you were right. I do get type info, but i can't cast it so i can't get it's properties. I still have so much to learn about this... so, in the end, it appears that my plan  won't work. Thank you for all your help :)